# How to make setTimeout in while loop execute sequentially in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I make the following simple while loop execute sequentially?

```
var x = 2;
var y = 10;
while (x<y) {
  x = x+2;
  setTimeout(function(){ y = y+1;
  }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Do you expect in each iteration `x = x + 2` and `y = y + 1`? Or you want to first add `x` to `10` then do `y  = y + 1` with same counts of `x = x + 2`?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead.

> `setTimeout` executes the function once on a time out. `setInterval` executes the function repeatedly on and interval

[*source*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825350/3083093)

To stop the interval, use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Example:

```
var x = 2,
    y = 10;
var loop = setInterval(function(){ 
    if(x<y) {
        x = x+2;
        y++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's the difference between setInterval and setTimeout?

Comment: so when the condition of x<y is false, will the loop automatically break?

Comment: @Makudex I added the difference.

Comment: @tom.denka I updated my code to stop the loop with clearInterval.

Comment: @R3tep *Why* does the question's code (presumably) not work? Is it, perhaps, related to [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty The question code does not work because all setTimeouts are started at the same time. The while loop does not wait until the first setTiemeout is executed before starting the second iteration. It loops on all iterations and starts the setTimeout after.

Answer (score 0):

If what you expect is do `x = x + 2; y = y + 1;` in each iteration until `x >= y` then you can do like:

```js
var x = 2;
var y = 10;
var func = function() {
  // While x is still smaller than y
  if (x < y) {
    x = x + 2;
    y = y + 1;
    console.log(x, y);
 
    // Register a timer to call self after 500ms if we still to loop.
    setTimeout(func, 500);
  }
};

// Manually start the function.
func();
```

The difference betweeen [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) is:

You need to call `setTimeout` in your callback to keep it loop until it mets the stop condition. While `setInterval` just need to call once, you may have to use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) to stop it to keep calling the `callback`.