# javascript settimeout inside loop and repeat

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contain some text descriptions. I want to display one element at a time with time delay (10 sec). After show all elements, it should be start again.

```
var d = 0;
var dataList = ["a","b","c"];//eg:
function ShowList()
{
    do{
       var descrip = dataList[d];
       document.getElementById('section1').innerHTML = descrip;
       d++;
       setTimeout(ShowList(),10000);

    }while(d < dataList.length);
}
ShowList();
```

I'll try with above code, but not working properly.

Comment: If you only want to display one element at a time, there is no need for the loop. A loop is synchronous, setTimeout is asupynchronous.

Comment: Also, make sure to do the wrap around at the beginning `if (d >= dataList.length) d = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead.

> `setTimeout` executes the function once on a time out. `setInterval` executes the function repeatedly on and interval

[*source*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825350/3083093)

Code example

```
var d = 0,
  dataList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

setInterval(function() {
  var descrip = dataList[d];
  document.getElementById('section1').innerHTML = descrip;
  d++;
  if (d >= dataList.length) {
    d = 0;
  }
}, 10000);
```

To stop the interval, use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Comment: The comparison needs to be `===`, not `>`. You never want `d` to have the value `dataList.length`.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers correctly say, you need to pass the function itself to `setTimeout`, not call the function.

What they are not saying is that using a loop won't work here because `setTimeout` is asynchronous. Just set the element content and call `setTimeout`:

```
var d = 0;
var dataList = ["a","b","c"];//eg:
function showList() {
    var descrip = dataList[d];
    document.getElementById('section1').innerHTML = descrip;
    d = (d + 1) % dataList.length;
    setTimeout(showList, 10000);
}
showList();
```

To start from the beginning, we use the modulus operator, so that `d` is always in the range `[0, d.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout(ShowList,10000);` instead of `setTimeout(ShowList(),10000);`

Comment: That alone won't make the code work. In fact, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Make a code snippet from this ;) My browser got hanged while trying to convert your code to a live snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In setTimeout you have to specify the name of the function, not the application. When you write `func()` you are executing the function and the result will be passed as the actual parameter of setTimeout. For example, if `func()` returns 2, when you write `setTimeout(funct(), 1000)` it is like you are writing `setTimeout(2, 1000)`.

Therefore write `setTimeout(ShowList, 10000);`

Comment: I tried, when remove brackets of function it start with third element (c) and then show 'undefined'

Comment: And this is a problem of closures: [Closures on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: @StefanoNardo : no it's not. Well, not specifically in this case. The logic of the function is simply incorrect.